# What is the grammar of "ごく" in "ごくかすか" mean?

Tags: words

"かすか" means "faint".
"ごくかすか" mens "very faint".

What part of speech is "ごく"? An inflection of "ごい"? What might either mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「ごく」 in 「ごくかすか」 is an adverb meaning "extremely".

In kanji, it is written as 「極{ごく}」.

[image]

This curry is named 「男{おとこ}の極旨黒{ごくうまくろ}カレー」, literally, "Extremely Tasty Black Curry for Men".

Comment: My full context was also writing: "ごくかすかな笑みを浮かべた"。So, it feels like maybe "すごくかすか" might be spoken and "ごくかすか" might be written. But each uses different kanji, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @David_W. 「[凄]{すご}く」「[極]{ごく}」の音が似ているのは偶然だと思います。